# Maintain package in cache Ext 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I created a package in ExtJS, and i have some applications that uses the package.

My question is:
How to maintain the package in cache after loading the new applications in browser ? i dont find anything in docs and in the internet.

Thanks

Comment: What cache are you talking about? Package cache of your Sencha CMD installation? Browser cache? What is the problem/issue?

Comment: Is browser cache ! basically is the javascript loaded by the internet (6MB), I dont want that the browser loads the JS included in my package all time when I refresh de applications in browser, sorry for my bad english

Comment: First of all, make sure your webserver returns [`304 Not Modified`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978189/how-304-not-modified-works) for static files. Apart from that, Ext JS can use what they call "Application Cache" and also HTML5 Local Storage Cache for storing files. That is easily googlable. Finally, use Sencha CMD to build a single app.js file containing only what your app needs rather than loading whole 6MB framework.

Comment: my webserver returns 304, the deal is maintain the 4.5MB from ext in cache. I'll study more from sencha app build to do this and search for the "Application cache". Thanks.