# Node.js: how to request an image only if it changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, request

I'm designing a node.js app.
One of its tasks is to regularly download a set of images from some public, external, site.
One requirement is to avoid repeating the download of images which are not changed from the previous download.
I plan to use "request" module, since it is far more complete and flexible with respect to other networking modules (please correct me if I'm wrong).

This is the code I'm using now (please ignore some mistakes, like comparing dates with `>` or `<` operators, consider it *pseudo-code*...):

```
var request = require('request');
var myResource = {
  'url': 'http://www.example.com/image1.jpg',
  'last-modified': 'Mon, 28 Sep 2015 08:44:06 GMT'
};

request(
  myResource.url,
  { method: 'HEAD'},
  function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error requesting header:', err);
    }
    var lastModifiedDate = res.headers['last-modified'];
    console.log('last modified date:', lastModifiedDate);
    if (lastModifiedDate > myResource['last-modified']) { // resource did change
      request(
        myResource.url,
        function (err, response, contents) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error('error requesting content:', err);
          }
          myResource['last-modified'] = lastModifiedDate;
          storeContents(contents); // store contents to DB
        }
      );
    }
  }
);
```

This code should work (in principle).
But I ask: `request()` is called twice: is this a waste of resources?
Could the content request be someway chained to the first request?
Can you suggest a cleaner / smarter / faster approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe i'm missing something, but if you know the `last-modified` date, you should send that as the `If-Modified-Since` header with the `GET` request and skip the `HEAD` request. The server should return a `304` when appropriate.

[How "304 Not Modified" works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978189/how-304-not-modified-works)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't remember about `If-Modified-Since` header... This is probably **the** answer... I'm accepting it soon :-)

Comment: @MarcoS if not, try `ETag`, but either way you should leverage the image server and response header and use only one request.

Comment: How can I trigger the resource download based on ETag? Does something like `If-Etag-different` exists?

Comment: @MarcoS, check the link in my post.