# How can I force browsers use expire (rather than etags/modification time)

Tags: performance, caching, browser-cache

I have a server serving static files with an expire of 1 year but my browsers still get the file and receive a 304 - not modified. I want to prevent the browser from even attempting the connection. I realize that that happens in several different setup (Ubuntu Linux) with Chrome and Firefox.

My test is as follows:

```
$ wget -S -O /dev/null http://trepalchi.it/static/img/logo-trepalchi-black.svg
--2016-03-14 19:56:14--  http://trepalchi.it/static/img/logo-trepalchi-black.svg
Risoluzione di trepalchi.it (trepalchi.it)... 213.136.85.40
Connessione a trepalchi.it (trepalchi.it)|213.136.85.40|:80... connesso.
Richiesta HTTP inviata, in attesa di risposta... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.2.1
  Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2016 18:55:29 GMT
  Content-Type: image/svg+xml
  Content-Length: 25081
  Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Mar 2016 23:03:53 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Expires: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 18:55:29 GMT
  Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
  Cache-Control: public
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
Lunghezza: 25081 (24K) [image/svg+xml]
Salvataggio in: "/dev/null"

100%[==================================================================================================================================================================>] 25.081      --.-K/s   in 0,07s   

2016-03-14 19:56:14 (328 KB/s) - "/dev/null" salvato [25081/25081]
```

That shows correctly providing expires and cache control (via nginx).
If I go to the browser and enable cache and open diagnostic tools, the first hit I notice a 200 return code, then I refresh the page (Control-r) and find a connection with 304 - not modified return code.

Inspecting firefox cache (about:cache) I found it with correct expire and clicking on the link in that page I was able to see it w/o hitting the remote server.

I also tested pages where the images are loaded from image tags (as opposed as directly called as in the example above).

All the letterature I read state that with such an expire the browser should not even try a connection. What's wrong? [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) states:

> HTTP caching works best when caches can entirely avoid making requests
>   to the origin server. The primary mechanism for avoiding requests is
>   for an origin server to provide an explicit expiration time in the
>   future, indicating that a response MAY be used to satisfy subsequent
>   requests. In other words, a cache can return a fresh response without
>   first contacting the server.

Note [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978189) addresses the problem of how 304 is generated, I just want to prevent the connection to be made
Sandro
Thanks

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978189/how-304-not-modified-works

Comment: That question addresses a different issue: how the 304 is generated. I want to investigate why a connection is attempted since I already got the file with a far in the future expire

Comment: I checked a few days ago on Chrome and images. 
It works exactly in the way you wanted. 
Chrome checks etag and modification date if file has already expired or if file does exist into the browser cache.
In that second case the server checks etag and modification date and it returns 304 if one of those is equal.
Of course on your server side you can decide the 304 behavior.
Please note I use expires, etag and modification date.....but I don't use the max age directive.