# Webservice returning 304

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a usercontrol which on load gets the number of items in a cart.

C# web project, VS 2013.

1. I add this control on the masterpage.

   2. I create a new aspx page and write code to add a product to a basket.
   3. Create an asmx file to return the count. Add the cs file to the App_Code folder. Create my asmx file pointing to the CS file in
      App_Code. I can navigate to the asmx webservice and confirm its
      working.
   4. Looking at this page http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/calling-web-service-using-scriptmanager580/
      I now add a ScriptManager to the masterpage to call the webservice.

What i'm trying to do is when the user adds an item to their cart the webservice is called and loads the control with the correct amount of items.

At present when the user adds an item the service is called but returns

```
myservice.asmx/js

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: private
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Qz4XGpz?=
```

So i navigate to the usercontrol page (by adding the control to a page) directly and can see the correct number of items but cant work out why the webservice is returning 304 when called.

My understanding is that 304 means the page is cached but not sure what i need to do next?

I can provide more code but hoping there is something simple I may have missed here?

**Edit 1**

**Request Headers**

```
GET /myService.asmx/js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:12345
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:12345/myproductpage
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=vSc1; XSRF-V=fiwSIljhKu74EC; __atuvc=4%7C26; __atuvs=5773d8720cbfe159003; SiteCookie=886c194f-e921-4587

**Response Headers**
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: private
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Qz4XGpz?=
```

Comment: Is it making a `GET` request? What are [the header values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978189/how-304-not-modified-works) regarding caching in the request?

Comment: I will look at that link and have added the headers within my original thread. Thanks